# "Error submitting the deployment request." for Microsoft Azure VM set up

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to set up a virtual machine on Microsoft Azure. I followed all the instructions, however, it gives me the follow message when I submitted it.

[image: error message]

Comment: The error mentions an invalid image `hortonworks.hortonworks-sandbox...`. Maybe there's something wrong with that image. Have you tried deploying any other images?

Comment: which instructions were you following? there are a variety of reasons this could happen, including: you don't have enough quota in your subscription (e.g. you are limited to 10 cores, and using this VM would put you over that limit; common on trial subscriptions), or you tried to use a public IP that was already in use, or other errors of this nature

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you don't have enough quota; you can get more quota by submitting a support request from the portal:

[image]